# Parsing PDF to CSV

Tags: python, pdf

I have a PDF which contains a table that I would like to get into Excel. I found pdftables (a Python library) which may be able to do the job but I am having a problem installing the library. I am running Python 3.7.4 with Anaconda. When I try to install using pip, I get an error. Can anyone either tell me how to install the library or suggest another way to parse the table?

```
pip install pdftables
Collecting pdftables
```

Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/68/c587103e6937acd2ac4f07538e8b09d76e75979ffe57ac7bc59f256a79d7/pdftables-0.0.4.tar.gz

Collecting pdfminer==20110515 (from pdftables)

Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/f8/512bcd1a116d0332ab9fab84c3771d4699216db1086e120d581535665c31/pdfminer-20110515.tar.gz

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /Users/ihf/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/y2/38gkkc0s7d52_mr_s6zfj7m80000gq/T/pip-install-_h1bkupj/pdfminer/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/y2/38gkkc0s7d52_mr_s6zfj7m80000gq/T/pip-install-_h1bkupj/pdfminer/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
cwd: /private/var/folders/y2/38gkkc0s7d52_mr_s6zfj7m80000gq/T/pip-install-_h1bkupj/pdfminer/

Complete output (8 lines):

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/private/var/folders/y2/38gkkc0s7d52_mr_s6zfj7m80000gq/T/pip-install-_h1bkupj/pdfminer/setup.py", line 3, in

from pdfminer import **version**
File "/private/var/folders/y2/38gkkc0s7d52_mr_s6zfj7m80000gq/T/pip-install-_h1bkupj/pdfminer/pdfminer/**init**.py", line 4
if **name** == '**main**': print **version**
^

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(**version**)?
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Comment: The package is written for Python 2....

Comment: Yes, I see that. I need something that will run using Python 3